# Force include a stylesheet from parent theme

Tags: css

I have a theme that includes the stylesheet /css/woocommerce.css
This stylesheet is also loaded in the child theme on shop pages.
BUT I want to be loaded and on post pages in order to style products that are showed by some plugins.
Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, by you could try something like the code below.
If first register your css as css-woocommerce (yout theme may allready have this) then you can on init use  wp_enqueue_style IF it is a post (is_single). 
Does this help you?

```
function register_custom_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_style( 'css-woocommerce', 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/woocommerce.css' );
}

function custom_stylesheet() {
    if ( is_single() { // if is post type, except attachments and pages
        wp_enqueue_style( 'css-woocommerce' ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_stylesheets' ); 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_stylesheet' );
```